# Can you burnish back of tefillin straps?

Tags: tefilin

We bought tefillin for our son, however the back/inner side of the shel yad have many spots where the leather is very abrasive.  Through wearing it the last 7 months most are smooth, but some still remain.  I don't want it to be an unpleasant experience (דרכיה דרכי נועם).  Is there any problem with burnishing (halachic or practical).  e.g. [this attachment](https://smile.amazon.com/Leather-Burnisher-2-Pack-Rotary-Dremel/dp/B0858X54T4/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=burnished%20leather%20tool&qid=1604250937&sr=8-3) with a rotary dremel together with [this gum tragacanth](https://smile.amazon.com/dp/B003BCUYK0?psc=1&pf_rd_p=3fd67503-0643-475d-bc98-343072208f68&pf_rd_r=5GNHPKHQ59NZJY4KVSWN&pd_rd_wg=3ztkz&pd_rd_i=B003BCUYK0&pd_rd_w=P8Qnw&pd_rd_r=f23edc77-34ad-4f00-ba53-6b842e999f4a&ref_=pd_luc_rh_pd_luc_ac_b_03_02_t_img_lh)

Comment: Consult your local Orthodox rabbi, or better yet, your sofer

Comment: Shouldn't be a problem. There seem to be 3 types of straps, some have very rough backs, some where that roughness has been somewhat smoothed and some very smooth, all seem to have gone through a different degree of processing in the factory / workshop.

Comment: in my experience, tefillin take a long time to "break in". 7 months isn't very long. give it some more time